# Prove by induction $4$ is a divisor of $(3^n +2n-1)\; ,n\ge1$

Tags: induction

Prove by induction $4$ is a divisor of $(3^n +2n-1)\; ,n\ge1$

**My idea:**

for $n=1$ ,$3^n+2n-1=4$

therefor true for $n=1$

now suppose this is true for $n=k$

i.e,. $4$ is the divisor of $3^k+2k-1$

we have to prove for $n=k+1$

so consider $ 3^{k+1}+2(k+1)-1=3.3^k+2k+1$  how to processed from here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  $3*3^k + 2k+1 = 3(3^k + 2k-1)-4k+4$

Answer (score 2):

To do this without magic,
look at the difference of
two consecutive terms.

This is

$(3^{n+1} +2(n+1)-1)-(3^n +2n-1)
=3^{n+1}-3^n+2
=3^n(3-1)+2
=2(3^n+1)
$.

Since
$3^n$ is odd,
$3^n+1$ is even
so
$2(3^n+1)$
is divisible by $4$.

This establishes the induction step.